# is there a way to pass two values in an input checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have made one checkbox and I have two values like 1 for "yes" and 0 for "No". I want to pass two values for one checkbox . Is this possible?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checked" value="">
<label class="label" for="checked"></label>
```

On this checkbox when I click it turns to no ( means 0 value will return)

If it would be possible with javascript then best for me .

Answer (score 1):

No. A checkbox will only send a value if it is checked.

Have your server side code test for the presence or absence of the value, not for a specific value.

Alternatively, use a pair of radio buttons.

Comment: Acutally i m using check box with image like thumb if user click on yes then value return will 1 and if user click on thumb again then value will return 0

Comment: The label you put on it has no bearing on how it works.

Comment: `<img>` would make more sense, but it still has no bearing on how the checkbox control works.

Comment: checkbox will be added in form but my question is I want to add two value in checkbox.

Comment: You said that. Checkboxes don't work that way. Write the logic that handles the submitted value to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by adding a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" .../>
```

and then on submit event of the form fill in the value based on the checkbox being checked or not.
Use the value of the input instead of the checkbox in the form handling.

Comment: That's a poor solution. It adds a needless dependancy on JS. If the JS fails for any reason, you won't get any value when the form is submitted.

Comment: I have one checkbox n I changed the checkbox appearance with image like thumb up n thumb down now I want to add value on this checkbox to save n get the value.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, it is subject to errors, and if there is a better way I'm all for it. But the question did specify that using Javascript was acceptable.